# Entity Framework Raw SQL IQueryable

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

In an ASP.NET MVC project we are using in some part of the application raw SQL to directly send a query to SQL Server. We are doing this for many reasons, one of them is because we need to call 2 different databases in the same query..

```
result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ResultsListModel>(sqlQuery,params...)
```

This returns an `IEnumerable` since there is no way to return an `IQueryable`, altough the `.SqlQuery` allows to call `.AsQueryable()` it doesn't really return an `IQueryable`.

So that means every time we call the query, the database is retrieving all the records into memory, not good performance.

After that we call `IPagedList` to page the results

```
result.ToPagedList(searchModel.Page ?? 1, searchModel.PageSize ?? PageSize);
```

We are thinking to recreate what `IPagedList` does with the `IQueryable`, call to `COUNT` the results and then take the results it needs from one result to another.

So, we'd do a query to `COUNT` all the results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "Rest of the query"
```

And then we'd do another query with the same `FROM` part but this time retrieving the columns and getting from one result to another to retrieve only the ones we need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         "All the columns we need", 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) as row 
     FROM 
         "Rest of the query") a 
WHERE 
    row > X and row <= Y;
```

Where X and Y would be the values based on the page we are on and the total count.

Do you think this is a good approach? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks OK. Anything that makes you doubt this approach?

Comment: Not really, I just wanted to share it because I haven't seen a solution like this. For us it is important not to bring all the results (20K-120K) and just bring the ones we need for the page. I'm surprised nobody has a solution for this...

Comment: Nobody? This is about the way EF implements skip/take with LINQ. So it should be OK. I think relatively few people execute raw SQL with paging.

Comment: Well, our main problem is we have to retrieve the users a client has from one database and retrieve all the users infor from a master database that all the users share...so LINQ is not an option here unless someone tells me there is a way to make a LINQ query to join tables from 2 different databases...and with good performance

Comment: Depending on the version of SQL Server you are using, you could also look into the OFFSET ... FETCH query feature https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/